# Expo ios 'FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h' file not found

Tags: react-native, expo, flipper

I'm trying to get Expo running with Flipper and [Redux Flipper Plugin](https://github.com/jk-gan/redux-flipper). This requires to install react-native-flipper. I installed the package with `npx expo install react-native-flipper`. When I try to run the ios build for expo `npx expo run:ios` I end up with the following error:

[image]

There also exists an Github issue on Flipper. [Issue](https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/4351)
Can somebody explain to me what I'm doing wrong?