# Expo Redux debugging without Remote JS Debug

Tags: react-native, debugging, redux, expo, flipper

is there a way to debug redux/redux-toolkit in expo without using the Remote JS Debug function from expo. I'm using react native skia which disables the mentioned functionality. My first approach was to use flipper with a redux debugger plugin. Sadly i cant get this running. Please also see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75520197/expo-ios-flipperkit-flipperclient-h-file-not-found).

Has somebody another idea?
Is it possible to prettify the metro logs somehow?

Comment: try use redux-logger

Comment: I tried that as well. But it gets truncated in flipper and uglyfied in the metro logs :( @suryadi